# My .ajax call isn't working

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I have a form on my website that pushes to my e-mail address. Previously before I wrote an ajax function the form would successfully push to my e-mail address. Only problem is when the user fills out the form it takes them to another page upon submitting the form. The HTML for my form is below.

```
            <form id="contact" method="post" action="E-mail-form.php" name="EmailFromMyWebsite">

                <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Your Name" title=" (Your name is required)"> <br />

                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Name@email.com" title=" (Your email is required)"> <br />

                <label for="message">Message/Comment</label> <br>
                <textarea name="message" class="required" placeholder="Leave a brief message" title=" (Please leave me a brief message)"></textarea> <br />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </form>
        </div><!-- /end #contact-form -->
```

The ajax call I wrote is...

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
var formData = $('#contact').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:"formData",
    url:"Email-form.php",
    success: function(data){
        $('#contact').html('<p>Your message has been sent</p>');
      }
   });
});
```

My javaScript console shows no errors so I think the problem is with my jQuery logic. On Chrome when I click submit I am redirected to my homepage. On Firefox the form submits but I am redirected to another page, therefore it is completely ignoring my AJAX call. Can someone with  AJAX experience tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also I would love to attach a message if the call fails. Can I add 'failure:' and for the value put a function just like I did for success?

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues

- your form is submitting normally
- you're attempting to post the wrong data

To prevent the form from submitting you can return false from the jQuery click handler or call preventDefault from the event object.
You are sending a string `"formData"` as the form data instead of the string in the `formData` variable

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(event){
  var formData = $('#contact').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:formData,
    url:"Email-form.php",
    success: function(data){
        $('#contact').html('<p>Your message has been sent</p>');
      }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  // or
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I put in formData as a string however I think my form is still submitting normally. I added 'return false;' after the success function and it still submits the way it was before.

Comment: Yea I tried that and still submits and takes me to a new page. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @user1605847 do you bind your click handler after the dom is ready?

Comment: No I actually made a basic mistake and didn't put it inside the $(function(){. I now corrected that and get a new problem. a 404 error (not found). Chrome is telling me it can't find my php file. Obviously it's there because it works without the ajax call so what's the problem?

Comment: I'm a dumbass I was missing the "-" in E-mail. It works now really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a follow up if I add... fail: function(data){
        $('#contact').html('<p>Your message was not sent</p>'); after success would that alert the user if it wasn't sent?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the normal form submit action is still taking place, even though you have an AJAX call as well.  An easy fix for this may be to simply change the button type from `submit` to `button`.  That way your click handler will still work, but it won't perform the default action of submitting the form on its own.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

Comment: Exactly. Or `<button type='button'>`.

Comment: I should have wrote in my initial post that I tried to get rid of that and/modify and it doesn't work. I just tried again and now it does nothing.